# PERSONAL.XLAM is being opened as read-only

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I've been using a PERSONAL.XLAM file for years in Excel 2013(?) with no issue. I am now using Excel for Office 365 and am having a problem using the same file.

I used to be able to open a workbook, PERSONAL.XLAM would open along with it, and I could go into Developer > Visual Basic, and change VBA code and save. Perfect.

Now, with Office 365, I get an error saying I can't save because PERSONAL.XLAM is read-only. I checked the Windows file attributes, and the Read-only checkbox is not checked, so I'm not sure why it would be opening as read-only.

In addition to now using Office 365, I'm also on an entirely new PC, so there might be something I'm missing, but I don't know what to do.

Edit: I think I found a new wrinkle. I moved the Personal file from my XLSTART folder to my desktop. If I open the Personal file directly from there, I get an error that says, "Sorry, Excel can't open two workbooks with the same name at the same time." Does that mean it is open somewhere else already?

Comment: It will be read-only if some other process (such as another instance of excel, which may not be visible) has it open.

Comment: I have ensured that Excel is completely closed, I open Excel, and I still am in the same situation. Would anything else have it open? How can I tell if another process has it open?

Comment: Any file in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` (i believe Personal is saved in that) is opened as Excel starts, making it "in-use".  Options could be **A)** saving a macro that, upon opening Excel workbooks to Load your .XLAM file (you mentioned it was opened alongside a workbook to be able to edit), or **B)** saving your code to XLSTART and utilizing it via QAB or the VBA Project.  I would recommend naming it something other than "Personal" as that has come connotations in itself.

Comment: I do have it saved in the XLSTART folder. I want the file to automatically open any time I open a workbook, and that is happening because it's in the XLSTART folder, right?. I also want to be able to edit the Personal.XLAM file. (I do have it named differently, but I thought it would help others find this question if I used that filename instead.)

Comment: @Robby I'd probably with with suggestion A, then.  Save your file in another location (non- AppData) and have your file opened Upon loading a new workbook, so it becomes editable.  Being in the folder used for initializing Excel, you won't be able to edit anything in there while Excel is open (though you can continually add new things to it).

Comment: Is that something new to Office 365? As I said, I was able to have it in the XLSTART folder using an earlier version of Excel.

Comment: @Robby In searching, this microsoft forums post describes it: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-save-edits-to-xlam/fe7e663f-2d22-4b3a-9aae-adf4a939ca04  I won't speculate further, as this could be umpteen thigns without knowing more specifics about your system, which leads to this being inappropriate for StackOverflow and more appropriate for SuperUser.

Comment: @Robby You could check that this isn't also listed in your shared folders (via compmgmt.msc), though that seems less likely considering there're several posts about stating that people have the same issue with newer software (appears to be editing anything in the AppData file the related file is open is a no-no, from some very quick reading).

Comment: I'm at work, so all the computers are administered, so I don't know if this is normal or not. But the C drive is listed as a Shared folder there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I actually had code in `Workbook_Open` that looked at the `Application.UserName`. If it wasn't a match for what it checked against, it made the Personal file read-only. And as I mentioned before, I got a new computer and my name was set to something different. After I changed my username back to what I used to use, everything is back to the way it was.

If it wasn't for that "security check," I wouldn't have had any issues. In other words, you **can** have the XLAM file in the XLSTART folder and make changes to it while you have it open, which is what I wanted.

*This is obviously a self-imposed, yet accidental, issue. I'll mark it as answered, but if it would be better to close it, that's fine too.*

Comment: Aww man! Finally found the exact question I had, but the solution is so specific - it doesn't apply to me. ☹